# Overriding Node.prototype.addEventListener breaks property binding in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following simple template:

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" />
  <input type="submit" [disabled]="!email"/>
</form>
```

This works fine on its own. When I type into "email" the submit button is enabled. However, if I override the addEventListener on Node.prototype, this stops working. I haven't been able to figure out why yet.

For example, I've added

```
<script>
  var ogListener = Node.prototype.addEventListener;

  Node.prototype.addEventListener = function (event, listener, useCapture) {
    console.log("Adding event: " + event);
    ogListener.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
  };
</script>
```

to the top of my index.html and the submit will no longer enable when I type into the email input.

Comment: One problem might be that `addEventListener` is inherited by `Node.prototype` from `EventTarget.prototype`, so you're overwriting it in the wrong place. (It still should work, though).

Comment: Huh, fwiw, that does fix the problem. Maybe I'm overwriting something that Angular is doing when I do it at that level. Thanks!